# WPF visibility binding not playing well with data trigger bound to visibility

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I can't figure out what the problem with this code is. Maybe you can spot something I don't see. My project builds just fine and the designer doesn't complain about anything. But, when I try to run it, it says that it can't create an instance of the window this code is in.

I think I have narrowed the problem down to the visibility binding coordinating with the data trigger. If I remove the visibility binding on that property and set it arbitrarily to true or false, it runs just fine. But I need this property to be dynamic.

```
<Image Visibility="{Binding ShowStatusMessageTabIcon, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}"
   Source="{Binding Source={x:Static bo:UserSession.Instance}, Path=HighestStatusMessageSeverity, Converter={StaticResource SeverityToImageConverter}}">
<Image.Style>
    <Style>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Visibility}"
                         Value="Visible">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource FlashErrorImage}" />
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="FlashErrorImage" />
                </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Image.Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your using a `Trigger` on a property of the `UIElement` itself you will want to use `Trigger` not `DataTrigger`, `DataTriggers` are more for changes in `DataObjects` in your model etc, normal `Triggers` are used for the `UIElements` etc.

```
   <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource FlashErrorImage}" />
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="FlashErrorImage" />
                    </Trigger.ExitActions>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
```

Here is a complete working mockup, if it helps narrow down the issue

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication7.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Name="UI">

    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />

        <Storyboard x:Key="FadeAnimation" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" >
            <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:5" />
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <Image Source="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconcreme/halloween/128/Skeleton-icon.png" 
               Visibility="{Binding ElementName=UI, Path=ImageVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" Height="247">
        <Image.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Name="Fade" Storyboard="{StaticResource FadeAnimation}" />
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                             <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Fade"  />
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Image.Style>
    </Image>
        <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Visible"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _imageVisible;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public bool ImageVisible
    {
        get { return _imageVisible; }
        set { _imageVisible = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("ImageVisible"); }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ImageVisible = !ImageVisible;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string p)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but, this answer doesn't work for me. It exhibits the same behavior as with the data trigger. If trigger of a property other than visibility, or if I set the visibility directly, it doesn't error out. Any other ideas? @sa_ddam213

Comment: Strange, working fine here, I even tested it before posting, are you sure you have ` <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}"> set?
`

Comment: I think I just figured out the issue. I was setting the datacontext for the control within the window constructor and when I move it to the Loaded event handler, it works just fine.

Comment: Also, using the data trigger instead of a regular trigger does work, but it may not be the best practice.

Comment: I added my mockup if it helps

Comment: Ohhh... I see its all sorted now :)